# Can't run on jenkins script from a repository, that requires authentication

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, groovy-console

I need to run on the jenkins groovy script from a repository, that requires authentication.
I can access this script using:

```
curl -u login:pass http://some-groovy-script.groovy
```

And I run on jenkis any script, that doesn't requires authentication:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins/ groovy http://some-groovy-script.groovy
```

But it doesn't work if scripts repository requires authentication, I get error 401.

Is there any way to combine this two actions in one and execute script on jenkins?

Comment: Not clear what you exactly need. If any repository require authentication, then how can Jenkins be an exception in that case?

Answer (score 0):

If you could access repository using ssh, then try configuring dropping ssh keys for the repo in jenkins user's ~/.ssh/ directory and configuring ~/.ssh/config for the jenkins user